# Java BufferedImage pixel[] getting the right pixel

Tags: java, arrays, canvas, pixel

Hello im trying to draw a rectangle using the pixel array that I got from

```
pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

But I cant seem to get the right pixel.

Im trying to use

```
public void p_fillRect(int color, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    for (int xpos = x; xpos < width; xpos++) {
        for (int ypos = y; ypos < height; ypos++) {
            pixels[xpos + ypos * em.getGame().getWidth()] = color;
        }
    }
}
```

but its not working as I expected please help!

Here is a link to the current state of the loop : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wrCD.jpg

Here is a link for the result of the program : https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9sbL.jpg

Comment: Why not use BufferedImage.setRGB(int x, int y, int color)?

Answer (score 0):

A couple questions/suggestions.

is `em.getGame().getWidth()` the width of the buffered image you are accessing the pixels from?

You could also try switch the yPos and xPos variables so your array would look something like this:

```
for(int ypos = y; ypos < height ypos++){
    for(int xpos = x; xpos < width; xpos++){
        pixels[xpos + ypos em.getGame().getWidth()] = color;
    }
}
```

What do you mean by you can't seem to get the right pixel? Does the rectangle show up just in the wrong place?

Edit: This method worked for me

```
BufferedImage canvas = new BufferedImage(canvasWidth, canvasHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Raster raster = canvas.getRaster();
int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) raster.getDataBuffer()).getData();

public void fillRect(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height){
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            pixels[(x*canvasWidth)+y] = someColor;
        }
    }
}
```

I render the canvas like so:

```
g.drawImage(canvas, 0,0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
```

Comment: Yes em.getGame().getWidth() is getting the width of the bufferedimage. And its not looking like a rectangle like i expected its more less a diagonal thick line. All i really need to know is how to get a pixel in 2d space from the one dimensional array of pixels. More less how do i do pixels[x][y] with only a one dimensional array?

Comment: @Kuliu your formula is right, x + (y * width). Have you tried changing your loop yet? Your original loop iterates through x, then y. For this formula, your loops should first iterate y, then x (as shown in this answer)

Comment: yes ive tried to change it but its giving me the same result :(

Comment: Here is a link to the current state of the loop : http://imgur.com/v0tjsYe

Here is a link for the result of the program : http://imgur.com/OrTxNUk

Comment: @Kuliu if solution posted in my edit still does not work I can just post my full code.